# Implement mechanism of sending messages every second

Tags: python, multithreading, rabbitmq, queue, thread-safety

I need to send messages that come from rabbitMQ to users every second. For these purposes, I use 2 threads. The first that takes messages from rabbitMQ and queues them up. The second thread takes messages from the queue, processes them, and sends them to users via a web socket. My question is how best to implement this mechanism.
Now my code looks like this:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.data = {}
    self.queue = Queue()

def download_data(self):
    started_time = time.perf_counter()
    while True:
        if time.perf_counter() - started_time >= 1:
            started_time = time.perf_counter()
            for _ in range(self.queue.qsize()):
                self.append_data(self.queue.get())
            self.sync_send_data_to_user(self.data)
            self.data = {}


def message_handle(self, ch, method, properties, body):
    message = json.loads(body)
    self.queue.put(message)
    ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)

def start_consuming(self):
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(RABBITMQ_HOST))
    channel = connection.channel()
    rabbit_queue = channel.queue_declare("to_client")
    channel.basic_consume(on_message_callback=self.message_handle, queue="to_client")
    threading.Thread(target=channel.start_consuming, args=[]).start()
```

This code works, but sometimes it sends messages more than 1 time per second. First thread is rabbitMQ consumer - callback function `message_handle` and second thread is infinite loop function `download_data`. `message_handle` checks if 1 second past and if this happend, `message_handle` blocks thread using queue until all items from queue will be retrieved.

**UPDATE:**
I think I made it harder for myself, I ended up changing the logic a bit. Now I have 2 threads, one of which processes messages from rabbitmq and sends them to the queue,function `message_handle`. Queue in python is thread-safe, so it should work. The second thread checks if 1 second has passed, if so retrieves all the data from the queue and sends it to the users, function `download_data`

Answer (score 0):

1. You're mixing AsyncIO (coroutines) with threading. The two are completely different approaches to concurrency that yield different behavior. A more reasonible approach would be to develop your solution using only one of the two. I'd go for an asyncio based solution and ensure I `await` where possible and not block the event loop.
2. Python suffers from [GIL](https://realpython.com/python-gil/) issues. So even though you thing you are doing stuff concurrently, you are in fact, bound to a single thread execution at any given time. If I add the previous section (creating multiple threads), you may encountered unexpected timing issues. Python is really not the best fit for perfect timing (it's also deeply affected by the local execution environment/load)
3. If you care about ensuring truly concurrent execution, you may have a look at [python multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html). Again, results may vary.